# Is it acceptable to ask the same question in two different Stack Exchange communities?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

If you have a question which is applicable to two or more different communities but you don't get an answer in the first community you post it to, is it acceptable to ask it in one or more others? If so, how long would people suggest waiting? 24 hours or so seems fair except in urgent situations...?

An example would be the following:

[openSUSE Leap 42.1 won't boot install as dual boot (works fine in VM)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275529/opensuse-leap-42-1-installs-fine-in-a-vm-but-refuses-to-dual-boot)

Which has yet to receive an answer on the Linux Stack Exchange, so I'm wondering if it would be acceptable to repost in Super User...?

Comment: Ask for the question to be migrated to a different SE. Don't create a new question there.

Comment: Is deleting then reposting acceptable practice would you say? I don't want to bother the moderators and make them do things for me if I can do them myself.

Comment: Yes, it's probably acceptable practice, but any comments or upvotes the original question obtained will be lost. And I wouldn't worry too much about bothering the mods. It's part of what they are here for.

Comment: I'll wait and see what happens. No-one seems to have any ideas yet.

Comment: Note, asking about something like this in chat is a reasonable alternative to posting a Meta question. It's a fairly common situation.

Comment: Meta meta: http://meta.superuser.com/q/11418/513541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons that I personally don't agree with, cross-posting is [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/203101) on the SE network. The general assumption is that your question fits one site better than all others. I realize this is often not the case, but them's the rules.

So, if you ask a question on site1.stackexchange.com and decide that it would be better off on site2.stackexchange.com, you can:

1. Delete your question from one site and repost on the other;
2. Flag your question for moderator attention and ask us to migrate it for you.

What you cannot do and should avoid is having the question on more than one site. If you do, you are likely to end up with both questions closed.